# Scikit-Learn GaussianHMM decode vs score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hidden-markov-model

What Exactly is the difference between decode and score? The documentation seems pretty sparse regarding this.

My guess is that:
decode represents the probability of the best sequence of states for a observation sequence.
score represents the sum of probabilities of all state sequences for a observation sequence.

Is this correct? That is, decode is the viterbi probability while score is the forward probability.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because seems to be about how a particular part of some software works rather than about a statistical issue. If this falls under the topics listed in the help, could you please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `decode`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.hmm.GaussianHMM.html#sklearn.hmm.GaussianHMM.decode):

> ```
> decode(obs, algorithm='viterbi')
> ```
>
> Find most likely state sequence
>   corresponding to `obs`. Uses the selected algorithm for decoding.
>
> Parameters :
>
> - `obs` : array_like, shape (n, n_features): 
>     List of
>     n_features-dimensional data points. Each row corresponds to a single
>     data point.
> - `algorithm` : string, one of the `decoder_algorithms`: decoder
>     algorithm to be used
>
> Returns :
>
> - `logprob` : float : Log probability of the maximum likelihood path through the HMM
> - `state_sequence` : array_like, shape (n,) : Index of the most likely states for each observation

And [for `score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.hmm.GaussianHMM.html#sklearn.hmm.GaussianHMM.score):

> `score(obs)`
>
> Compute the log probability under the model.
>
> Parameters :
>
> - `obs` : array_like, shape (n, n_features) : 
>     Sequence of n_features-dimensional data points. Each row corresponds to a single data point.
>
> Returns :
>
> `logprob` : float : 
>   Log likelihood of the obs.

So, yes, `decode` gives you the most likely sequence of hidden states for an observation sequence, as well as its log probability, using (by default) the Viterbi algorithm. `score` gives you the probability of the observed state sequence, marginalizing out all the possible hidden states.

Comment: "score gives you the probability of the observed state sequence, marginalizing out all the possible hidden states." Is this the same as forward probability (alpha probabilities)? i.e. sum of probabilities of all paths through the HMM.

Comment: @adi Yes, those are the same thing.